# Can I publish both with Apple Books and Amazon?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, organization, scientific-publishing, amazon

I want to publish my book both through Apple Books and Amazon. Is this allowed? Or if I choose to provide my book through Apple, then I am obligated to not sell it through any other platform?

Comment: check the terms and conditions, it will say there.

Comment: I did, I didnt quite get it to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same book.  Very unlikely.  Read your contract terms.

Two different books.  Very likely.  Read your contract terms.